# Customizing Doclib Filter in Alfresco Share

Tags: share, alfresco

In Alfresco 4.0, I'd like to extend Share Doclib Filter webscript to add my own customized filter.

1. Is there a simple way to add my own filter in the `share-config-custom.xml`?
2. How do I define my own filter on the repository side?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 steps involved:

- Adding the link by customizing the document library with your own module(see alfresco Help):

  ```
  <customization>
    <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco.components.documentlibrary</targetPackageRoot>
    <sourcePackageRoot>com.company.components.documentlibrary</sourcePackageRoot>
  </customization>
  ```

extend the webscripts `filter.get.js` and `repo-filter.get.js` (add them in `web-extension / site-webscripts / com / company/ components / documentlibrary /` )

```
var filters = model.filters;
filters.push(
      {
         id: 'myExtension',
         data: '',
         label: 'link.myExtension'
      });

model.filters = filters;
```

extend the property file with your own labels

- Override the repository webscript to add your own filter interpretation:

in  `alfresco / templates / webscripts / org / alfresco / slingshot / documentlibrary-v2 /`

Copy paste the `filters.lib.js` and add your logic:

```
case "myExtension":
                filterQuery = "+PATH:\"" + parsedArgs.rootNode.qnamePath + "//*\"";
                filterQuery += "+@blabla\\:isLikeThat:\"FALSE\"";
                filterParams.query = filterQuery + filterQueryDefaults;
                break;
```